# loop over a csv column and getting the largest number

Tags: python, csv, max

I am trying to loop over the first column in a CSV file,
but when I do so, the double digits get ripped apart and each digit is being treated as one

```
def largest(path: str):
    new_list = []  
    with open(path, 'r') as read:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(read)
        for row in csv_reader:
            int_row = row['label']
            for i in int_row:
                new_list.append(int(i))

    print(max(new_list))
largest('sign-language-mnist\data\sign_mnist_train.csv')
```

the column I am looping over is as below

[image: csv image]

how do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int_row` is the entry for that row. You shouldn't iterate over it, which will just iterate over its individual characters (as you've seen), but instead convert it to an `int`:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    int_row = row['label']
    new_list.append(int(int_row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new_list.append( int(j) for j in i)
```